# How to handle input file with non standard delimiters in dsx ml pipeline?

Tags: data-science-experience

I'm trying to work with a data set that has no header and has `::` for field delimiters:

```
! wget --quiet http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-1m.zip
! unzip ml-1m.zip
! mv ml-1m/ratings.dat .
! head ratings.dat
```

The output:

```
1::1193::5::978300760
1::661::3::978302109
1::914::3::978301968
```

I have loaded the file into my dsx pipeline, but I am unclear how to get dsx to split this file using the `::` delimiters.

- How do I do this?
- If it is not possible to get dsx to reshape this file using dsx ml pipeline functionality, does dsx have any pre-requisities in terms of input file format?

**Update:**

The ml pipeline functionality I'm trying to use can be seen from the screenshot below:

[image]

I have added a data set, but can't figure out how to get dsx to recognise the field delimiters:

[image]

Comment: DSX provides a bunch of APIs. Could you be a bit more specific about which one you'd like to use for processing the file? I assume you're using notebooks here, not R Studio. But do you want to work with Python, R, or Scala? Would it be acceptable to read the file into memory using a Python lib or Scala function, and feed it from there into the ML pipeline? Would it be acceptable, as a last resort, to convert the file format with some bash commands from a Python notebook, and then process the converted file?

Comment: I've updated the question with more info.  I was expecting to see functionality in the pipeline ui to help with this preprocessing, maybe that is a misunderstanding on my part.  I was also working under the assumption that you work with notebooks *or* pipelines, but not both.  If i need to work in the notebook as well as the pipeline, I would probably do everything in the notebook?  If we need to process data before uploading it to the pipeline, what format should we convert it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Feb-2017...

When you create a new pipeline and select a dataset, I believe DSX loads the file you select using a Spark [DataFrameReader](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader).  The DataFrameReader defaults to using a single `,` as the delimiter.   DSX does not provide a way to change the default delimiter in the UI.

I think preprocessing the data is your best option.  You can do this in a notebook.  Be aware that the Spark DataFrameReader only supports a single character delimiter, so you can't use that with this particular dataset.  You can user pandas, however.

```
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.read_csv('ml-1m/ratings.dat', sep='::', 
              header=None, 
              names=['UserID','MovieID','Rating','Timestamp'], 
              engine='python')

pdf.to_csv('ratings.csv', index=False)

!head ratings.csv
UserID,MovieID,Rating,Timestamp
1,1193,5,978300760
1,661,3,978302109
1,914,3,978301968
1,3408,4,978300275
1,2355,5,978824291
1,1197,3,978302268
1,1287,5,978302039
1,2804,5,978300719
1,594,4,978302268
```

Now the data will be in a format that DSX will be able to parse properly.